# Second command in vim macro not run since update to vim 8.1

Tags: vim

I'm having a problem with a macro since I have updated from vim 8.0 to 8.1 (as packaged in ubuntu 18.04 and ubuntu 20.04 respectively).

This is my macro:

```
let @g = ':Gcommit --no-edit --amend %^M:Gpush -f^M'
```

which uses fugitive vim to make a commit and then a push.

This macro works perfectly with vim 8.0, but with vim 8.1 the commit is made, but the push isn't made.

I think the problem may be that the push is tried to be made before the commit is actually completed, but I'm not sure.